# How to calculate current position on a great circle path

Tags: objective-c, math, geometry, geolocation

Given a starting point (origLat, origLon), ending point (destLat, destlon), and a % of trip completed. How do I calculate the current position (curLat, curLon)?

Comment: What circle are you talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Aviation Formulary](http://edwilliams.org/avform.htm) is a great resource which covers this question and more.

Comment: Just keep in mind that those formulas assume a spherical model. Formulas exist for ellipsoids (WGS84 and such) but they will be far more complicated. It all depends on your presicion requirements.

Comment: Works well. Though as Lawnmower says it is an estimate based on sphere. If anyone can provide a link to the same algorithm for a WGS84 model I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are no longer simple formulas when moving to ellipsoids, but you have to use iterative approximations. Start at http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/geodesic.html and see the references linked there. Maybe you can use the library directly or look at the code.

Answer (score 3):

[MTL](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) provides some good content on great circle computations and some working applets you can use to verify your implementation.

Answer (score -3):

In this case, it should be really simple:

```
curLat = origLat + percentageOfTripCompleted*(destLat-origLat);
curLon = origLon + percentageOfTripCompleted*(destLon-origLon);
```

*The fact that the earth is a sphere really has no bearing on this problem.

Comment: That is not a great circle path.

Comment: That is incorrect. Look at the link in @hfs's answer. Remember, great circle paths are *not* straight lines.

Comment: thinking about this one a little more, that is definitely true.  my bad.

Comment: Technically speaking, if the distance is very short, this may be a valid approximation.

Comment: @ysap Unless you're close to the central meridian, in which case this route might take you for a longer stroll :-)